# How do I send an emit from a child to a parent when using Vue and <script setup>?

Tags: vuejs3

I have a simple parent component and child component...

```js
    <script setup>
    import ChildComponent from "...";
    function onAdd(){
      ...
    }
    </script>
    <template>
      <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
    <template>
    
    <script setup>
    function doSomething(){
      // call onAdd
    }
    </script>
    <template>
    <div>
    <div @click="doSomething></div>
    </div>
    </template>
```

What I would like to do is call `onAdd` from the child component. How would I go about doing this?

I tried this (sorry changed from onAdd to refreshRecords)...

```js
//Parent
<script setup>
async function refreshRecords() {
  console.log("Refreshing");
}
</script>
<template>
  <Child :refresh-records="refreshRecords"></Child>
</template>

// Child
<script setup>
const emits = defineEmits(['refresh-records']);
async function onSubmit(){
  ...
  console.log("Emitting");
  emits('refresh-records', {});
}
</script>
<template>
  <q-form @submit="onSubmit" class="q-gutter-md" >
    ...
    <q-btn label="Submit" type="submit" color="primary" />
  </q-form>
</template>
```

The refresh never gets called but I see the `Emitting` message

Answer (score 2):

It is something like this:

**Parent**

```js
<script setup>
import ChildComponent from "...";
function onAdd(val){
  ...
}
</script>
<template>
  <ChildComponent :on-add="onAdd"></ChildComponent>
<template>
```

**Child**

```js
<script setup>
defineEmits(['on-add'])
function doSomething(){
  // call onAdd
}
</script>
<template>
<div>
<div @click="$emit('on-add', value)"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

**Or child**

```js
<script setup>
const emits = defineEmits(['on-add'])
function doSomething(){
  emits('on-add', value)
}
</script>
<template>
<div>
<div @click="doSomething"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I am still having issues, no error but the on-add never seems to get called after emit. Does it matter if the onAdd function is async?

Comment: Or it could be the on submit

Comment: @Jackie don't think so it should work. Hope your value is a Ref or Reactive value. This is important in async data.